# Occasional duplicate keys when typing on Dell Insiron 7547 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, dell, inspiron

I am running ubuntu-gnome 14.10 on a Dell Inspiron 7547.
Occasionally when typing, pressing some keys tends to register them as a duplicate-press instead of single press. I've noticed that the keys 's','n','m', 'l', 'c', backspace have this problem and I suspect more do.

This computer didn't have such a problem when it run M$-Windows.

I couldn't manage to fix/workaround it via the gnome keyboard settings, specifically via the keyboard repeat rate/delay settings.

This is a problem especially during login. If the password contains any of the duplicated keys, login fails.

Key presses do not seem to register as duplicated if I space out the typing one key at a time, as in one key per sec.

It also seems that the duplication somewhat depends on the strength of hitting the key. When pressing it very gently, keys are rarely duplicated, while hitting the keys with a bit more confidence surfaces the problem at a higher frequency.

Does that sound like a buggy keyboard driver? 
I like this system but the keyboard issue makes it difficult to work with.
Any advice?

Comment: This sounds like buggy hardware...  Can you try a different keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I cannot reproduce this problem with USB keyboards

Answer (score 0):

You have a hardware problem:

1. Download the service manual for your machine
2. order a replacement keyboard from your manufacturer
3. Remove the broken keyboard
4. Add the replacement keyboard

### Done

**Why?** The labour is more expensive then the part: replacing your keyboard yourself is easy and will save you a lot of money! (2 **→** 4 screws is all it takes)

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If this answer helped you, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your delay\input lag from your keyboard its too low (settings > Universal Access). This was happening to me, after i reduced the input lag, just raise a little bit and it was ok again.